# Why does this ANTLR grammar generate the "wrong" result?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

For this grammar: (I'm eliding the rest, will include it below.)

```
defaultBooleanExpression
  : nested += maybeAndExpression (nested += maybeAndExpression)+
  ;

fuzzyQuery
  : text =
      ( UNQUOTED
      | UNSIGNED_NUMBER
      | SIGNED_NUMBER
      )
    TILDE
    (similarity = UNSIGNED_NUMBER)?
  ;
```

If I input this:

```
abc~0.5
```

I expect to get a structure like:

```
{ fuzzyQuery text=abc similarity=0.5 }
```

But what I actually get is:

```
{ defaultBooleanQuery
  { fuzzyQuery text=abc similarity=null }
  { unquoted text=0.5 }
}
```

The code I'm using to run the parser is as follows. We're applying a performance hack as suggested in the FAQ...

```
        QueryLexer lexer = new QueryLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(tokens);
        parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.SLL);
        ParseTree expression;
        try
        {
            expression = parser.startExpression();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            parser.reset();
            parser.getInterpreter()
                  .setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.LL);
            expression = parser.startExpression();
        }
```

Debugging it:

- First round, it goes inside defaultBooleanExpression(), then goes inside fuzzyQuery(), recognises all three tokens as part of fuzzyQuery(), then exits fuzzyQuery(). Then there are no tokens left, so defaultBooleanExpression() fails because there aren't enough clauses, and this causes the parse to fail.
- We catch the exception and then retry with LL(*).
- Now, it goes inside fuzzyQuery(), but for some reason the prediction fails to see the third token, so it stops at the '~'. It then completes without throwing an exception, but returns the wrong result.

I attempted to use ANTLRWorks 2 and the IDEA plugin to try and debug the syntax rule by rule, but neither of these tools appear to work at the moment - they both refuse to parse the grammar without printing any kind of error to explain why.

Full grammar follows.

```
/**
 * Grammar specification for our query syntax.
 */
grammar Query;

@header {
package com.nuix.storage.textindex.search.queryparser.antlr;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Parser Rules

startExpression
  : expression EOF
  ;

expression
  : maybeOrExpression
  ;

maybeOrExpression
  : orExpression
  | maybeDefaultBooleanExpression
  ;

/**
 * e.g., a OR b
 */
orExpression
  : nested += maybeDefaultBooleanExpression (OR nested += maybeDefaultBooleanExpression)+
  ;

maybeDefaultBooleanExpression
  : defaultBooleanExpression
  | maybeAndExpression
  ;

/**
 * e.g., a b
 */
defaultBooleanExpression
  : nested += maybeAndExpression (nested += maybeAndExpression)+
  ;

maybeAndExpression
  : andExpression
  | maybeProximityExpression
  ;

/**
 * e.g., a AND b
 */
andExpression
  : nested += maybeProximityExpression (AND nested += maybeProximityExpression)+
  ;

maybeProximityExpression
  : withinExpression
  | notWithinExpression
  | precedingExpression
  | notPrecedingExpression
  | maybeUnaryExpression
  ;

/**
 * e.g., a W/4 b
 */
withinExpression
  : left = maybeUnaryExpression op = W_SLASH_N right = maybeUnaryExpression
  ;

/**
 * e.g., a NOT W/4 b
 */
notWithinExpression
  : left = maybeUnaryExpression NOT op = W_SLASH_N right = maybeUnaryExpression
  ;

/**
 * e.g., a PRE/4 b
 */
precedingExpression
  : left = maybeUnaryExpression op = PRE_SLASH_N right = maybeUnaryExpression
  ;

/**
 * e.g., a NOT PRE/4 b
 */
notPrecedingExpression
  : left = maybeUnaryExpression NOT op = PRE_SLASH_N right = maybeUnaryExpression
  ;

maybeUnaryExpression
  : notExpression
  | plusExpression
  | minusExpression
  | maybeBoostedQueryFragment
  ;

/**
 * e.g., NOT a
 */
notExpression
  : NOT nested = maybeBoostedQueryFragment
  ;

/**
 * e.g., +a
 */
plusExpression
  : PLUS nested = maybeBoostedQueryFragment
  ;

/**
 * e.g., -a
 */
minusExpression
  : MINUS nested = maybeBoostedQueryFragment
  ;

maybeBoostedQueryFragment
  : boostedQueryFragment
  | maybeFieldedQueryFragment
  ;

/**
 * e.g., a^2.0
 */
boostedQueryFragment
  : nested = maybeFieldedQueryFragment CARET boost = UNSIGNED_NUMBER
  ;

maybeFieldedQueryFragment
  : plainFieldedQueryFragment
  | subFieldedQueryFragment
  | wildcardSubFieldedQueryFragment
  | queryFragment
  ;

/**
 * e.g., properties:a
 */
plainFieldedQueryFragment
  : fieldName =
      ( UNQUOTED
      | LONE_WILDCARD
      | TO
      )
    COLON
    nested = queryFragment
  ;

/**
 * e.g., integer-properties:"File Size":3
 */
subFieldedQueryFragment
  : fieldName =
      ( UNQUOTED
      | LONE_WILDCARD
      | TO
      )
    COLON
    subFieldName =
      ( QUOTED
      | UNQUOTED
      )
    COLON
    nested = queryFragment
  ;

/**
 * e.g., date-properties:*:20010101
 */
wildcardSubFieldedQueryFragment
  : fieldName =
      ( UNQUOTED
      | LONE_WILDCARD
      | TO
      )
    COLON
    subFieldName =
      ( UNQUOTED_WILDCARD
      | QUOTED_WILDCARD
      | LONE_WILDCARD
      )
    COLON
    nested = queryFragment
  ;

queryFragment
  : fuzzyQuery
  | unquotedQuery
  | dateOffsetQuery
  | unquotedWildcardQuery
  | loneWildcardQuery
  | slopQuery
  | rangeQuery
  | groupQuery
  | unquotedMacro
  | quotedMacro
  | geoDistanceQuery
  ;

/**
 * e.g., GEODISTANCE((40N 50E) 60km)
 */
geoDistanceQuery
  : GEODISTANCE
    LPAREN
    LPAREN
    latitude =
      ( UNQUOTED
      | UNSIGNED_NUMBER
      | SIGNED_NUMBER
      )
    longitude =
      ( UNQUOTED
      | UNSIGNED_NUMBER
      | SIGNED_NUMBER
      )
    RPAREN
    distance =
      ( UNQUOTED
      | UNSIGNED_NUMBER
      )
    RPAREN
  ;

/**
 * e.g., "some query"~2
 */
slopQuery
  : nested = slopCapableQuery
    ( TILDE slop = UNSIGNED_NUMBER )?
  ;

slopCapableQuery
  : quotedQuery
  | quotedWildcardQuery
  | exactQuery
  | regexQuery
  ;

/**
 * e.g., a
 */
unquotedQuery
  : UNQUOTED
  | UNSIGNED_NUMBER
  | SIGNED_NUMBER
  ;

/**
 * e.g., +2Y
 */
dateOffsetQuery
  : DATE_OFFSET
  | TODAY
  ;

/**
 * e.g., query~0.8
 */
fuzzyQuery
  : text =
      ( UNQUOTED
      | UNSIGNED_NUMBER
      | SIGNED_NUMBER
      )
    TILDE
    (similarity = UNSIGNED_NUMBER)?
  ;

/**
 * e.g., a*
 */
unquotedWildcardQuery
  : UNQUOTED_WILDCARD
  ;

/**
 * e.g., *
 */
loneWildcardQuery
  : LONE_WILDCARD
  ;

/**
 * e.g., "a"
 */
quotedQuery
  : QUOTED
  ;

/**
 * e.g., "a*"
 */
quotedWildcardQuery
  : QUOTED_WILDCARD
  ;

/**
 * e.g., 'a'
 */
exactQuery
  : QUOTED_EXACT
  ;

/**
 * e.g., /a+/
 */
regexQuery
  : QUOTED_REGEX
  ;

/**
 * e.g., $a
 */
unquotedMacro
  : DOLLAR
    name = UNQUOTED
  ;

/**
 * e.g., $"a"
 */
quotedMacro
  : DOLLAR
    name = QUOTED
  ;

/**
 * e.g., [a TO b}
 */
rangeQuery
  : lowerBoundSymbol = ( LBRACE | LBRACKET )
    lowerBound = rangeQueryBound
    TO?
    upperBound = rangeQueryBound
    upperBoundSymbol = ( RBRACE | RBRACKET )
  ;

rangeQueryBound
  : unquotedQuery
  | dateOffsetQuery
  | quotedQuery
  | loneWildcardQuery
  ;

/**
 * <p>e.g., (a)</p>
 *
 * <p>If a ~N style suffix is present then the thing inside can only be an OR query. TODO: Not enforced yet though</p>
 */
groupQuery
  : LPAREN nested = expression RPAREN
    ( TILDE minimumMatches = UNSIGNED_NUMBER )?
  ;



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Lexer Rules

// Most specific rules go first, otherwise the more general ones will blot them out.

AND         : ('A'|'a')('N'|'n')('D'|'d') | '&' '&' ;
OR          : ('O'|'o')('R'|'r')          | '|' '|' ;
NOT         : ('N'|'n')('O'|'o')('T'|'t') | '!' ;
TO          : ('T'|'t')('O'|'o') ;

UNSIGNED_NUMBER : Digit+ ('.' Digit+)?
                | '.' Digit+
                ;

SIGNED_NUMBER : ( '+' | '-' ) UNSIGNED_NUMBER ;

DATE_OFFSET : ( '+' | '-' ) UNSIGNED_NUMBER ('D'|'d'|'W'|'w'|'M'|'m'|'Y'|'y') ;

GEODISTANCE
  : ('G'|'g')('E'|'e')('O'|'o')('D'|'d')('I'|'i')('S'|'s')('T'|'t')('A'|'a')('N'|'n')('C'|'c')('E'|'e')
  ;

PRE_SLASH_N
  : ('P'|'p')('R'|'r')('E'|'e') '/' UNSIGNED_NUMBER
  ;

W_SLASH_N
  : ('W'|'w') '/' UNSIGNED_NUMBER
  ;

TODAY
  : ('T'|'t')('O'|'o')('D'|'d')('A'|'a')('Y'|'y')
  ;

UNQUOTED
  : UnquotedStartChar
    UnquotedChar*
  ;

LONE_WILDCARD
  : '*'
  ;

UNQUOTED_WILDCARD
  : ( UnquotedStartChar
      UnquotedChar*
    )?
    ( WildcardChar
      UnquotedChar*
    )+
  ;

fragment
UnquotedStartChar
  : EscapeSequence
  | ~( ' ' | '\r' | '\t' | '\u000C' | '\n' | '\\' | ':'
     | '"' | '\u201C' | '\u201D'    // DoubleQuote
     | '\'' | '\u2018' | '\u2019'   // SingleQuote
     | '(' | ')' | '[' | ']' | '{' | '}' | '~'
     | '&' | '|' | '!' | '^' | '?' | '*' | '/' | '+' | '-' | '$' )
  ;

fragment
UnquotedChar
  : EscapeSequence
  | ~( ' ' | '\r' | '\t' | '\u000C' | '\n' | '\\' | ':'
     | '"' | '\u201C' | '\u201D'    // DoubleQuote
     | '\'' | '\u2018' | '\u2019'   // SingleQuote
     | '(' | ')' | '[' | ']' | '{' | '}' | '~'
     | '&' | '|' | '!' | '^' | '?' | '*' )
  ;

QUOTED
  : DoubleQuote
    QuotedChar*
    DoubleQuote
  ;

QUOTED_WILDCARD
  : DoubleQuote
    QuotedChar*
    ( WildcardChar
      QuotedChar*
    )+
    DoubleQuote
  ;

fragment
QuotedChar
  : EscapeSequence
  | ~( '\\'
     | '"' | '\u201C' | '\u201D'      // DoubleQuote
     | '\r' | '\n' | '?' | '*' )
  ;

fragment
WildcardChar
  : ( '?' | '*' )
  ;

QUOTED_EXACT
  : SingleQuote
    ( EscapeSequence
    | ~( '\\' | '\'' | '\r' | '\n' )
    )*
    SingleQuote
  ;

QUOTED_REGEX
  : '/'
    ( EscapeSequence
    | ~( '\\' | '/' | '\r' | '\n' )
    )*
    '/'
  ;

fragment
EscapeSequence
  : '\\'
    ( 'u' HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
    | ~( 'u' )
    )
  ;

fragment
Digit
  : ('0'..'9')
  ;

fragment
HexDigit
  : ('0'..'9' | 'a'..'f' | 'A'..'F')
  ;

// Single character fragments (not tokens, but become part of tokens)
// U+2018  LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
// U+2019  RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
fragment SingleQuote      : '\'' | '\u2018' | '\u2019';
// U+201C  LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
// U+201D  RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
fragment DoubleQuote      : '"' | '\u201C' | '\u201D';

COLON     : ':' ;
PLUS      : '+' ;
MINUS     : '-' ;
TILDE     : '~' ;
CARET     : '^' ;
DOLLAR    : '$' ;
LPAREN    : '(' ;
RPAREN    : ')' ;
LBRACKET  : '[' ;
RBRACKET  : ']' ;
LBRACE    : '{' ;
RBRACE    : '}' ;

WHITESPACE : ( ' ' | '\r' | '\t' | '\u000C' | '\n' ) -> skip;
```

Comment: Have you checked what your lexer produces? Maybe it's generating tokens that don't match your parser rules?

Comment: It generates the three tokens I expect - {UNQUOTED, abc}, {TILDE, ~}, {UNSIGNED_NUMBER, 0.5}. Workaround-wise, if I make the unsigned number compulsory, the grammar picks it up. But in our syntax, it's supposed to be optional.